# Postfix "Relay access denied"

Tags: postfix

I have built a new Postfix Server and have the following Problem.
When I try to send a mail with the command "Mail" from another Server and the recipient is in another Domain i get "Relay access denied" in the Logs on the Postfix Server.

However it does work when I send it to the same Domain with the Mail Command or when using Thunderbird.

My understanding is that if the Server is in "mynetworks" it should work without Authentication but it seems I'm doing something wrong.

The following is the output of postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
allow_min_user = no
allow_percent_hack = no
biff = no
body_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks.pcre
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
enable_original_recipient = no
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
lmtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
lmtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
message_size_limit = 15728640
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, server02.domain.ch
mydomain = server01.domain.ch
myhostname = server01.domain.ch
mynetworks = ['127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.0/24']
myorigin = server01.domain.ch
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
postscreen_access_list = permit_mynetworks, cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr
postscreen_blacklist_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map = texthash:/etc/postfix/postscreen_dnsbl_reply
postscreen_dnsbl_sites = zen.spamhaus.org*3 b.barracudacentral.org*2
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 2
postscreen_dnsbl_whitelist_threshold = -2
postscreen_greet_action = enforce
proxy_read_maps = $canonical_maps $lmtp_generic_maps $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $mynetworks $recipient_bcc_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relay_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relocated_maps $sender_bcc_maps $sender_canonical_maps $smtp_generic_maps $smtpd_sender_login_maps $transport_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $smtpd_sender_restrictions $sender_dependent_relayhost_maps
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
recipient_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_user.cf proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_domain.cf
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = $mydestination proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf
sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_dependent_relayhost_maps.cf
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp-amavis_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtp_tls_CAfile = $smtpd_tls_CAfile
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname reject_invalid_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject_unknown_recipient_domain reject_non_fqdn_recipient reject_unlisted_recipient permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_login_maps.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject_unknown_sender_domain reject_non_fqdn_sender reject_unlisted_sender permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh2048_param.pem
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh512_param.pem
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDC3-SHA, KRB5-DE5, CBC3-SHA
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
swap_bangpath = no
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_maps.cf proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/catchall_maps.cf proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did sovlve it. I used the wrong syntax for mynetworks
I tried

```
mynetworks = ['127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.0/24']
mynetworks = '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.0/24'
```

but it needed to be

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.0/24
```

even though the comment in the main.cf right before is

```
#       MYNETWORKS = ['xx.xx.xx.xx', 'xx.xx.xx.0/24', ...]
```

Comment: If you solved it, accept your answer. You do not need to add "[SOLVED]" to the head of the question.